# Removing link from root category on topmenu

Tags: magento2, php, phtml, magento-2.2.5

I am trying to make the topmenu root category not clickable using this method

> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Remove-links-to-top-categories-in-menu/td-p/77072

but it doesn't seem to work. Anybody as a solution for this I've been looking for the past 5 hours.

Comment: Hello @Gabriel, Did my solution worked for you ? Or you need any help ?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

The reference link you added in question is working fine and disabling click on top level category. However if above solution not worked for you alternatively you can achieve this by using `jQuery`.

You can use:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery("a.level-top").prop("href", "javascript:void(0)");
  });
});
```

Above code will replace all top level `href` to `javascript:void(0)`

Comment: It's Working.....!

Comment: glad to know :)